# How to get innertext from xml node that has '\' along with other characters when fetched as string

Tags: c#, xml, oracle

Hi i am facing an issue extracting innertext from an xml script saved as varchar2 in my oracle database. 
While fetching i am getting the xml in the following format:

```
    "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<SpecificAction xmlns=\"http://www.xyz.com/schemas/core/caut\">action to take</SpecificAction>"
```

the following xml is fetched using the code below:

```
    instance.cautDescription = records.GetStringOrDefault("SPEC_ACTION");
```

the field SPEC_ACTION is of VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE) type.

due to the presence of \ character in the xml from database i am not able to extract the inner text withing the  Tag. I tried the following code for fetching the inner text:

```
    string s = instance.cautDescription;
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

            xmlDoc.LoadXml(s);

            XmlNode specificAction = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/SpecificAction");
            string specific = specificAction.InnerText;
            xmlString = specificAction.InnerText;

            return xmlString;
```

My code is returning null can this be avoided if so how , any support would be really helpful.

Comment: This is because of the namespace(xmlns). You meed to use XmlNamespaceManager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is classic problem when working with XML having default namespace. In XML, when you have default namespace (namespace without prefix, like `xmlns="...."`), all elements without prefix considered in default namespace. But in XPath, all elements without prefix considered has no namespace. To bridge this different paradigm, you need to declare a prefix that point to default namespace URI and use it in XPath :

```
var nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
nsManager.AddNamespace("ns", xmlDoc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
XmlNode specificAction = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/ns:SpecificAction", nsManager);
string specific = specificAction.InnerText;
```

Comment: how to fetch from more sub tags ?

Comment: That's broad unclear question that can lead to long explanation about XPath or LINQ-to-XML. You should be more specific. Anyway, different question should be asked in different post, not in comment.

Comment: `<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<annotation:Text xmlns:annotation=\"http://www.xyz.com/schemas/core/annotation\">Road not taken</annotation:Text>` 
Again xml of this type can the above mentioned method be used.

Answer (score 0):

Since the "SpecificAction" node has a namespace, you will need to supply a namespace manager.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(s);

XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("xyz", "http://www.xyz.com/schemas/core/caut");
XmlNode specificAction = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/xyz:SpecificAction", ns);

return specificAction.InnerText;
```